# How do I efficiently use the same interrupt handler for every (identical) peripheral port?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller, cortex-m

(Hopefully) simplified version of my problem:

Say I'm using every GPIO port of my cortex M-4 mcu to do the exact same thing, like read the port on a pin-level change. I've simplified my code so it's port-agnostic, but I'm having issues with a nice solution for re-using the same interrupt handler function.

1. Is there a way I can use the same interrupt handler function while
   having a method of finding which port triggered the interrupt? Ideally some O(1)/doesn't scale up depending on how many ports the board has.
2. Should I just have different handlers for each port that call the same function that takes in a "port" parameter? (Best I could come up with so far)

So like:

```
void worker (uint32_t gpio_id) {
    *work goes here*
}

void GPIOA_IRQ_Handler(void) { worker(GPIOA_id); }
void GPIOB_IRQ_Handler(void) { worker(GPIOB_id); }
void GPIOC_IRQ_Handler(void) { worker(GPIOC_id); }
...
```

My actual problem:

I'm learning about and fiddling around with FreeRTOS and creating simple drivers for debug/stdio UART, some buttons that are on my dev. board, so on. So far I've been making drivers for a specific peripheral/port.

Now I'm looking to make an I2C driver without knowing which interface I'm gonna use (there are 10 I2C ports in my mcu), and to potentially to allow the driver code to be used on multiple ports at the same time. I'd know all the ports used at compile-time though.

I have a pretty good idea on how to make the driver to be port-agnostic, except I'm getting hung up on figuring out a nice way to find which port triggered the interrupt using a single handler function. (besides cycling through every port's interrupt status reg since that's O(n)).

Like I said the best I came up with is to not have a single handler and instead have different handlers on the vector table that all call the same "worker" function in it and passing a "port" parameter. This method clutters up the driver code, but ***it is*** O(1) (unless you take code-complexity into account).

3. Am I going about this all wrong and should just "keep it simple stupid" and implement the driver according to the port(s)/use-case I will actually need in the simplest way possible? (don't even have plans to use multiple I2C buses, just though it'd be interesting to implement)

Thank you in advance, hopefully the post isn't too ambiguous or long (I feel like it's pretty long sry).

Comment: you could have a handler for each, that handler sets a register to indicate which interrupt it was then branch to the common handler which can then use that register or whatever hint.   Yes obviously you can set the same handler for any/every interrupt if desired.

Comment: What is your real problem here?  Flash consumption?  How big is your handler?

Comment: My problem is essentially how to avoid code duplication by using the same handler function for multiple interrupts, but also have a constant-complexity method of finding the source peripheral of the interrupt. 
I also wasn't sure if there was even a way to accomplish that, which probably resulted in a confusing post/question.

Comment: Handler isn't very big. For my actual problem of an I2C driver, it'll just be the standard "transmit/receive next byte if there is one ; wake up task when no more bytes to process", which could be even simpler if I used a DMA operation, but I'm not looking to go that deep right now.

Comment: If you can factor out any individual parameters, go for the solution 2 of your post. However, you need to write all these `*handler() { ...}` lines, because they provide the specific arguments and commonly install the vectors. Using "clever" assembly tricks would make the source a nightmare to maintain. -- I would start with 2 handlers, each implemented in its own rolled-out handler. Next I would develop the final algorithm, DMA or anything else. Only then I would investigate where the differences are, and consider refactoring in the sense of DRY.

Comment: @EmbeddedManuel DMA in itself can be a pain to set up, but it can lead to both faster and more readable code overall. Particularly true when dealing with serial buses like I2C or UART, having an interrupt trigger per byte received is quite painful (although the old school way of doing things).

Comment: @thebusybee Yea that's what I'm gonna go for. This post was really more of a reassurance that I'm doing things correctly than anything, which is every useful since this is a solo project into more-or-less new territory. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Lundin I completely agree! I definitely want to eventually implement DMA, specially since I'm implementing this for FreeRTOS. The only real reason I'm hesitant to go for it is that for my board (tiva C series) you can only have DMA enabled for either the slave or the master in I2C, so implementing it requires extra work to check & set-up safely. Definitely in my to-dos lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is there a way I can use the same interrupt handler function while having a method of finding which port triggered the interrupt?

Only if the different interrupts are cleared in the same way and your application doesn't care which pin that triggered the interrupt. Quite unlikely use-case.

> 2. Should I just have different handlers for each port that call the same function that takes in a "port" parameter?

Yeah that's usually what I do. You should pass on the parameters from the ISR to the function, that are unique to the specific interrupt. Important: note that the function should be `inline static`! A fast ISR is significantly more important than saving a tiny bit of flash by re-using the same function. So in the machine code you'll have 4 different ISRs with the worker function inlined. (Might want to disable inlining in debug build though.)

> Am I going about this all wrong and should just "keep it simple stupid"

Sounds like you are doing it right. A properly written driver should be able to handle multiple hardware peripheral instances with the same code. That being said, C programmers have a tendency to obsess about avoiding code repetition. "KISS" is often far more sound than avoiding code repetition. Avoiding repetition is of course nice, but not your top priority here.

Priorities in this case should be, most important first:

1. As fast, slim interrupts as possible.
2. Readable code.
3. Flash size used.
4. Avoiding code repetition.

Comment: Thank you, you answered everything I had doubts about, particularly on the last question. Unfortunately this being a new account I can't upvote it. 
+1 though